# Is every regular polygon the unit ball for some norm?

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

For every regular polygon, is there a norm such that the polygon is it's unit ball centered on 0?

Comment: Since $\|-x\|=\|x\|$, this cetainly fails for odd-gons.

Answer (score 4):

Since $\|-x\|=\|x\|$, this cetainly fails for odd-gons. -- [Hagen von Eitzen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035406/is-every-regular-polygon-the-unit-ball-for-some-norm#comment2110319_1035406)

On the other hand, it holds for even number of sides. See [Minkowski functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_functional).

Comment: Can you please explain how the minkowski functional related to it? we covered it briefly in our functional analysis course but I don't see the connection.